# node.js - Send POST data with raw json format with require module

Tags: json, node.js, rest, api

we have storage array which supports REST API. I am able to do all ( GET/POST/DELETE/PUT) through postman and need to implement one of POST operation through Node.js script.

I am successful in node.js GET operation. But still not able to get the simple POST operation through multiple tries with various forms. here is the codes of both GET and PUT. Also the successful POST operation screenshot by the postman.

Appreciate any help.

## GET: Node.js code ( working ):

```
var request = require('request');
function get_trustyou(trust_you_id, callback){
  var options = {
    url: 'https://xxxxxx/api/json/v2/types/consistency-groups',
     rejectUnauthorized: false,
      method: 'GET',
      type: 'application/json',

   auth:{
      user: 'xxxxx',
      pass: 'xxx'
    }
  };
  var res = '';
  request(options, function ( error, resp, body ) {
    if ( !error && resp.statusCode == 200){
         res = body;
     }
     if (error) {
       console.log("this is error" + error);
     }
     callback(res);
  });
}
get_trustyou("674fa44c-1fbd-4275-aa72-a20f262372cd", function(resp){
    console.log("Here is the result" + resp);
});
```

## POST: Node.js code ( Not working ):

```
var request = require('request');
function get_trustyou(trust_you_id, callback){
  var options = {
    body: postData,
    url: 'https://xxxx/api/json/v2/types/consistency-groups',
     rejectUnauthorized: false,
      method: 'POST',
      type: 'application/json',
      auth:{
         user: 'xxxx',
         pass: 'xxxxx'
       },
      form: {
        'consistency-group-name': 'TEST-CG'
          } 

};
  request(options, function ( error, resp, body ) {
    if ( !error && resp.statusCode == 200){
        res = body;
       }
     if (error) {
       console.log("this is error" + error);
     }
     callback(res);
  });
}
get_trustyou("674fa44c-1fbd-4275-aa72-a20f262372cd", function(resp){
    console.log("this is the responce" + resp);
});
```

Comment: You haven’t shown the working postman requests. You also need to share the logs you get.

Comment: i attached it earlier, somehow it didn't work. here is the link of pic: https://lsblogstorage.blob.core.windows.net/lacontainer1/POST-postman.png

Comment: but what's the error you are getting?

Comment: Its not getting anything like errors and on top its not posting data on storage server too.

Comment: Did few changes like adding headers, its working . thank you.